# With Android and OpenGL ES 1.0, why is my 1440 x 320 pixel background down-scaled to my Frustum Width and Frustum Height (480 x 320)?

Tags: android, opengl-es

With Android and OpenGL ES 1.0, why is my 1440 x 320 pixel background down-scaled to my Frustum Width and Frustum Height (480 x 320)?

```
background = new Texture(game, "scrolling_background.png");
backgroundRegion = new TextureRegion(background, 0, 0, 1440, 320);

batcher.beginBatch(Assets.background);
batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x, cam.position.y, FRUSTUM_WIDTH, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT, Assets.backgroundRegion);
batcher.endBatch();

cam.position.x = 240
cam.position.y = 160
FRUSTUM_WIDTH = 480
FRUSTUM_HEIGHT = 320
```

My immediate is to only display one third of my background each screen with the ultimate goal at  to implement a 2D scrolling background.  My original rationale was because the view frustum / view port is only 480 pixels in width and my original image is 1440 pixels in width, I will only see 1440 / 480 or 1/3 of the background each screen shot.

However, the entire image appears to be down-scaled to fit the view port.  I thought that it had to do with the fact that my default load texture method uses G10.GL_NEAREST for both the minification and magnification filters:

```
private void load () {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
    textureId = textureIds[0];

    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = fileIO.readAsset(fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        width = bitmap.getWidth(); // added by me to fix TextureRegion
        height = bitmap.getHeight(); // added by me to fix TextureRegion
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        setFilters(GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load texture '" + fileName + "'", e);
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public void reload () {
    load();
    bind();
    setFilters(minFilter, magFilter);
    glGraphics.getGL().glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

So I decided to set both the minification and magnification filters to GL10.GL_LINEAR thinking this would make a texture with 1:1 mapping by doing this:

```
background = new Texture(game, "scrolling_background.png");
background.setFilters(GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
background.reload();
```

I'm sure it is something simple. Any guidance or help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the spritebatcher.draw prototype:

public void drawSprite(float x, float y, float width, float height, TextureRegion region) {

```
    float halfWidth = width / 2;
    float halfHeight = height / 2;

    float x1 = x - halfWidth;
    float y1 = y - halfHeight;
    float x2 = x + halfWidth;
    float y2 = y + halfHeight;

    // bottom left

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;  
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    // bottom right

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    // top right

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    // top left

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    numSprites++;



}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with NEAREST / LINEAR.

Please try :

`batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x, cam.position.y, 1440, 320, Assets.backgroundRegion);`

It would be usefull if you specified which library you are using to render sprites (LibGDX ?) and also the prototype of this drawSprite function ?

I suppose those 2 parameters represent the final size on screen you want for the sprite, so if you want scrolling this size should be greater than the "frustum" as you call it.

Comment: Well, Mario Zechner, LibGDX's author wrote this framework that I'm using as the basis for the LibGDX framework which he would later write.  

    cam.position.x = world.background.position.x;
  
  batcher.beginBatch(Assets.background);
  batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x, cam.position.y, 1440, 320, Assets.backgroundRegion);
        batcher.endBatch();

The line of code you recommended renders the scene much better, except that no matter if cam.position.x's value is 0, 720, or 1440, I always see the middle of my background.  I never see the beginning nor do I ever see the end....

Comment: VB_overflow, I'm sorry.  You were right.  I'm slow on the uptake.  I noticed the following:

    // This shows left side background
   // batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x + FRUSTUM_WIDTH,        cam.position.y, world.background.width, world.background.height, Assets.backgroundRegion);
  
    // This shows the middle background
   //batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x, cam.position.y, world.background.width, world.background.height, Assets.backgroundRegion);

Comment: // This shows right side background
   //batcher.drawSprite(cam.position.x - FRUSTUM_WIDTH, cam.position.y, world.background.width, world.background.height, Assets.backgroundRegion);